# Postgres: CPU bound CREATE INDEX

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I am running postgres server on a slowish older computer with a fast SSD disk, 2,4 GHz i5 processor, and 8 GBs of RAM. The computer is not a speed monster but I am surprised by the performance. Creating index in a table with 40,000,000 rows takes roughly half an hour. My settings are the following:

```
max_connections = 2
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
work_mem = 1GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

When I looked at `top` output it looks like I am CPU bound (100% CPU) although the memory used by the database was around 500 MB and I would expect it to use more.

I am going to create the index only once per table during first data import. Are there any settings I could tweak to speed up this operation?

Comment: If you're CPU bound... there isn't much more that you can tweak.

Comment: Is is a computationally expensive index? That would explain it. Maybe you can show the `CREATE INDEX` statement. Does it get faster if you increase `maintenance_work_mem`?

Comment: I'll check with `maintenance_work_mem`. The creation is simple, `CREATE INDEX index_name on name (varcharField);`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how much should I increase `maintenance_work_mem`? Also is the time "normal by any means"? First encounters with progress so it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: You could try with 1GB `maintenance_work_mem` and see if that makes it faster. It really seems slow - on our systems we get about ten times that speed. To see where the time is spent, you could profile with [perf](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Profiling_with_perf) or [OProfile](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Profiling_with_OProfile) if you are on Linux (requires debugging symbols).

Comment: @ LaurenzAlbe After increasing the maintenance_work_mem and creating a database with `C` locale as opposed to the one default on my system, it took only 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

After increasing the `maintenance_work_mem` to 1GB and initialising the database cluster with `C` locale as opposed to the one default on my system, it took only 2 minutes.